# Garage Light mystery

Tags: electrical

I have 4 fluorescent fixtures in my garage and one was broken, so I replaced it. But now 2 of them will not turn on even though there is 120v going to each one. So, I replaced both of those and they still will not come on. What gives?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This may be a record: four minutes to a correct answer. You should definitely mark @j-raefield's answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from the little information you provided, but as a gross generalization, things like this tend to be a loose connection and from the sounds of it, a loose *neutral* connection because the neutral is common to everything.

Comment: That was it. One of the common wires had escaped. Thanks for solving that one for me J. Much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you should accept the answer.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance..